# Adding mobile/ to application domain in CFML

Tags: regex, replace, coldfusion, cfml

I'm having trouble with embedded page links on a mobile site I've inherited. The CMS obviously wants to use the desktop site for all its page links, which is taking people way from the mobile version.  I'm a complete n00b in CFML and I'm sure it's pretty simple, but I need to get every link on the page that currently shows as:

http://www.example.com/

to be replaced with:

http://www.example.com/mobile/

I looked at REGEX and my brain melted. Please can someone show me how to do a replace for this? Thank you :)

PS I don't have application.cfm in the /mobile folder where I would expect to specify a new domain like this. I tried it but on clearing the cache it hangs the site so I've had to remove it.

Comment: John, that's a pretty broad architectural question and it would depend a lot on the CMS and how things are currently architected. Is /mobile/ (the folder) a separate codebase - separate pages etc?

Comment: It runs off the root CMS but has different page layouts in the /mobile folder as it was an afterthought. Is there not one line of code I can put in the page that will scan and replace at will?

Comment: That's a question about your CMS John, not Coldfusion. Coldfusion dictate how you create a link. you can create an absolute or a relative link and you can fiddle with paths globally or individually in dozens of ways. You would need to get us some code snippets if we are to help you.

Comment: All I want to do is run a search on a page in CFML. How that isn't ColdFusion I don't know!
Wordpress does it like this:

<?php
function replace_content($content)
{
  $search  = array('http://example.com', 'http://www.example.com/');
  $replace = array('http://example.com/mobile', 'http://www.example.com/mobile');

  $content = str_replace($search, $replace, $content);
  return $content;
}

?>

That simple...

Comment: John, your question did not read (to me) as a search and replace question - more like a link management question. Sorry I misunderstood!

Comment: No worries, yeah it's a weird old system I've inherited that has a new mobile site with links back to the main site, quick and dirty wins the race lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid further overcomplication, I mixed it up with jQuery...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href^='/']").each(function(){ 
    var cur_href = $(this).attr("href");
    if( cur_href.indexOf( "http" ) !== -1 ) {
        $(this).attr("href", cur_href);
    } else {
        $(this).attr("href", '/mobile'+cur_href);
    }  
  });
});
</script>
```

The links turned out to be relative, else it would have been one line of code using the application domain variable.